# GCSToBigQueryOperator doesn't work inside python operator

Tags: airflow, etl

When I use GCSToBigQueryOperator it works but putting inside function and calling from python operator gives me below error;

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery.py", line 336, in execute
logical_date=context["logical_date"],
KeyError: 'logical_date'

Here is my code;

```
def fn_gcs_to_bqstg():
      task1 = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
           task_id='gcstobqstg',
           bucket=GCS_BUCKET,
           source_objects=['data/*.json'],
           destination_project_dataset_table='local_development.table',
           schema_object='schemas/data_schema.json',
           source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
           create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
           write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
           gcp_conn_id='bq-conn',
           dag=dag
      )
      task1.execute(dict())

gcs_to_bqstg = PythonOperator(
      task_id='gcs_to_bqstg',
      python_callable=fn_gcs_to_bqstg)
```

Is there any issue or solution to using GCSToBigQueryOperator inside the function?

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using? For example if its below Airflow 2.0, it might be as easy as passing provide_context=True to your PythonOperator.

Comment: Another issue might be use of context=["logical_date"], I am not sure this actually exists. Looking at the [task instance context output source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/352b970010846eb4168aa7b2e332d9a95e2facb3/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1659), you can see there is no 'logical_date'. You might be better served to use 'execution_date' for example

Answer (score 0):

I think the right approach would be to create a custom operator and to use its context for the `GCSToBigQueryOperator`.

```html
class CustomGCSToBigQueryOperator(BaseOperator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomGCSToBigQueryOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):

        task1 = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
           task_id='gcstobqstg',
           bucket=GCS_BUCKET,
           source_objects=['data/*.json'],
           destination_project_dataset_table='local_development.table',
           schema_object='schemas/data_schema.json',
           source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
           create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
           write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
           gcp_conn_id='bq-conn',
           dag=dag)
        task1.execute(context)
```